# Solving this finite factorial/binomial series

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I am staring at the following finite series:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^s A_k Y^k $$

I am trying to solve it for $Y$. $A_k$ is given by

$$ A_k = {s \choose k}\nu^k (1-\nu)^{s-k}$$

I already solved that

$$ \frac{A_k}{A_{k-1}} = \frac{s-k+1}{k} \frac{\nu}{1-\nu}$$

Hence I can rewrite the series as

$$ A_1\sum_{k=1}^s \prod_{j=1}^k\left(\frac{s-j+1}{j} \frac{\nu}{1-\nu}\right) Y^k$$

for some constant $A_1$. However, I am stuck here. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Since $Y^k\nu^k=(Y\nu)^k$, our sum,  apart from the missing term $k=0$,  is the Binomial Theorem expansion of $(Y\nu +1-\nu)^s$. So our sum is $(Y\nu+1-\nu)^s-(1-\nu)^s$.